# Can't set any Isolated Cores in local/virtual TwinCAT PLC

Tags: windows, twincat

For the past 3 years I have been using the TwinCAT IDE and local/virtual PLC without problems. I have a i7-8750H with 6 cores and 12 logical processors and I am using TwinCAT build 4022.20 Lately I am getting random Blue Screen of Death (BSoD). I got the advice to set an Isolated Core in the Real-Time section of the IDE, clicking on "Set on target" and decreasing the number of available CPU cores:

[image: Set on target form]

Then a restart is needed, The problem is that when I click on "Read from target" after restarting and reopening TwinCAT I got one less Windows core but no isolated core available:

[image: Real-Time tab]

I tried to run the "C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System\win8settick.bat". Also to reduce from 12 down to 7, with no success: one by one, in steps of 2 and 3, nothing seems to work.

I have tried also using the Msconfig tool to reduce the number of cores for Windows with the same result.

[image: Error message]

I can manually set the right number of CPUs for Windows and Isolated but when I try to run my application I got a message saying that my config doesn't match my target, if I dismiss I get an BSoD or my laptop freezes immediately.

[image: Virtual Box Warning]

VirtualBox is not running, so I am not sure why I get this message.

Any idea why TwinCAT can't see the isolated core?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to partially solve the problem, I still can't get any isolated cores, but at least I do not get any BSOD or laptop freeze. Just did this:

1. Open a Command prompt with admin rights
2. type "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"
3. reboot

Source: https://www.sps-forum.de/threads/twincat-3-4024-10-visual-studio-2019-xar-adserror-4132-hyperv-problem.101584/

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version (Tc3.1.4024.17) there is a User MOde Runtime implemented.
It is still in Beta, no realtime!!

But i tried it and it works with hypervisor and virtualization, got the recommendation from the Beckhoff Support.
[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tEjz.png)

Use the "Start.bat" and select UmRT_Default as Target System for the PLC.
Then you can activate the Configuration and go into Run.

Known Limitations:
As it is still under development, not every function is supported
(not working with NC, as i tested)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately we are stuck with a previous version of TwinCAT, clients are usually reluctant to change.

Answer (score -1):

Biggest question is; what changed (that got you in to problems)?

Did you change Windows (for instance 32 bit W7->64 bit W10)? I found that with 64 bit Windows (10) TwinCAT (which is then also 64 bit) crashes some of the times when running on a non-isolated core.

Furthemore I found that below build somewhere in the twenties, TwinCAT 4022 has problems with recent (past 2 years) W10 versions. Please try 4022.32 (the latest and final 4022 version).

I have a i7-9850H and run the latest W10 64 bit and have 1 of my 12 threads running isolated. TwinCAT 4024.12 runs without problems on this isolated core.

Comment: The only thing that could have changed is Windows 10, maybe an update? I use and have always 64b W10 with no issues. I've being using 3.1.4022.20 for quite a while with no problems. some colleagues run the same SW setup, just with a i7 7700 processor and they manage to get an isolated core, I can't but can't see why.

Comment: Could you try 4022.32?

Comment: Hi owillebo, thanks for your time trying to help me. I did try with Twincat 4022.32 with the same result. I have updated the description of the problem to remark that I get a warning just before the problem occurs: "Setting TwinCAT in Run Mode with Virtual Box running might fail" But I do not have VirtualBox Running, or in the background that I am aware of.

Comment: Consider updating Twincat to the newest version 4024.12

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as our clients use 4022.20 and I need this particular version to test and validate changes. Even if 4024.12 works it doesn't explain why some of my colleagues have no problem with 4022.20

Comment: See https://alltwincat.com/2018/06/14/twincat-virtualization
TwinCAT crashes when it shares threads with Virtual Box.
Why does TwinCAT 'think' Virtual Box is running?

Comment: I don't know why it thinks it's running. Just in case I remove VirtualBox from my system, now I do not get the warning message, but still can't get an isolated core when doing "Read from target"

Comment: "... TwinCAT I got one less Windows core but no isolated core available: ..." How did establish this? Note that 11/1 after the 'Read from target' dialog means; 12 cpus in total, 11 of which non-isolated and 1 isolated.

Comment: Sorry, the images were swapped, I just edit them. The image that shows the result of "read from target" is the one that shows the Real-time tab. [11/0] and should be [11/1]